# How to load a pandas dataframe that is stored as pickle or feather (df.pkl or df.ftr) into sqldf

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqldf, pandasql

I have two files - df.pkl and df.ftr.
And I am using run_qry = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals()) to run sql queries.
So for example:
I am creating a new DataFrame like new_dfr = run_qry("""select * from df""") but I need to load the df.pkl or df.ftr in run_qry(sqldf) to run this query.

Can you tell me, how to do load previously created DataFrame here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are just trying to load dataframes from pickle and feather files?

If so I think you can use the [pandas.read_pickle()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_pickle.html) and [read_feather()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_feather.html) methods:

```
import pandas as pd
df_pkl = pd.read_pickle(pickle_file_path)
df_ftr = pd.read_feather(feather_file_path)
```